# Didn't Cassie's 'Me and U' (from 2006) have deep bass notes in it?

Tags: hip-hop

I recall hearing [this song](https://youtu.be/zVJ5gsLeCSM) long, long ago a few times and really liking the juxtaposition of deep bass notes with high-pitched (thought not shrill) ones. Now, I hardly hear any bass notes in it, and the difference between the high and low notes isn't as much as I remember. Also, I thought she sang this song with a higher pitch.

Did I just mis-remember the song, or is this a consequence of my hearing aging? I've heard that your ability to hear low notes declines as you age, so now I'm scared that I just can't appreciate this song anymore as it was meant to be heard. And I have high-dollar gaming head phones, so I doubt my headphones could just not be capable of playing the low notes. That is possible, but if it is, these headphones are still better then $10 dollar ones I had been using before (I finally got sick of the things giving out on me every few months, and so I broke down and bought an expensive set hoping they would last longer). If it matters, they're rig 400 'surround sound' head phones. I don't know what the sound card is; it came with the computer. My system information gives two, realtek high definition audio and nvidia high definition audio (didn't even know that nvidia made sound cards?)

Comment: Memory can sometimes play tricks on us. :)

Answer (score 3):

Putting the song through a frequency analyser shows nothing unusual in the frequencies of this song. The synth kick-drum sounds are at about 50Hz. It doesn't sound particularly bass-heavy. It seems like your memory is deceiving you.
[Age-related hearing loss](http://www.pykett.org.uk/arhlandob.htm)  usually affects the higher frequencies much more than the lower ones.